# Why would I get, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'helpers' of undefined"?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

I've got this html in my Meteor project:

```
<head>
  <title>The Dentist Hurt My Fillings</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Thirteen Ways of Looking at a Duckbilled Platypus</h2>

<br/>
<br/>

<div class="container">
   {{> whizzardBlizzard}}
</div>

</body>

<template name="whizzardBlizzard">
    <form>
    {{#if firstStep}}
    {{> firstStepTemplate}}
    {{/if}}
    {{#if secondStep}}
    {{> secondStepTemplate}}
    {{/if}}
    {{#if thirdStep}}
    {{> thirdStepTemplate}}
    {{/if}}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button">
    </form>
</template>

<template name="firstStepTemplate">
  <h2>Step 1</h2>
</template>

<template name="secondStepTemplate">
  <h2>Step 2</h2>
</template>

<template name="thirdStepTemplate">
  <h2>Step 3</h2>
</template>
```

...and this Javascript:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // stepNum starts at 1
  Session.setDefault('stepNum', 1);

  Template.whizzardBlizzard.events({
      "submit form": function (event) {
          //event.preventDefault();
          // save the vals to a new document in a collection
          Session.set('stepNum', Session.get('stepNum') + 1);
      }
  });

  Template.whizzardBlizard.helpers({
     'firstStep': function() {
         return (Session.get('stepNum') == 1);
     },
     'secondStep': function() {
         return (Session.get('stepNum') == 2)
     },
     'thirdStep': function() {
         return (Session.get('stepNum') == 3)
     }
     // . . .  etc.
  });

}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

When I try to run it, I get, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'helpers' of undefined"?

How could that be? Template helpers are a key component of Meteor, and examples of its usage mirror mine.

I have tried it both with and without encasing the helper name (such as "firstStep") in single quotes; that is, I've tried both this:

```
firstStep: function() {
```

..and this:

```
'firstStep': function() {
```

...while calling it like so:

```
{{#if firstStep}}
    {{> firstStepTemplate}}
{{/if}}
```

So why is 'helpers' reportedly unreadable?

Comment: I am almost sure it boils down to a load order issue: You try to define your helper before your template itself is defined.

Comment: So what can I do to avoid that?

Comment: Because it *is* .. undefined. So then; *why*? The debugger - if stopped - will be pretty good at showing the current state, including inspection of the stack.

Comment: No, it's not undefined. The question is, assuming Kyll is right, how to arrange things so that it is not referenced from the .js file prior to the definition in the .html file from being executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Blizzard* in your helper only has one "z": *Blizard*

Comment: If this is the right answer then the question should be closed as a typo.